# PUG template engine POST request with dropdown data

Tags: javascript, express, pug

I am attempting to submit a POST request using express and pug mainly atm. My problem is I am able to post all of my data in the form below except for the 2 dropdowns that load in which are Class and Rarity. The code is extremely simple in PUG, I am just not quite sure how to make it so the POST request contains the selected option for both.

```
form(action="/cards" method="POST")
           p Artist: 
               input#artist(name="artist" type="textbox")
           p Name: 
               input#name(name="name" type="textbox")
           p Min Attack: 
               input#minattack(name="mina" type="textbox")
           p Max Attack: 
               input#maxattack(name="maxa" type="textbox")
           p Min Health: 
               input#minhealth(name="minh" type="textbox")
           p Max Health: 
               input#maxhealth(name="maxh" type="textbox")
           p Class: 
               select#class
                   each val in options
                       option(name="class" type="option")=val
           p Rarity:
               select#rarity
                   each val in rarity2
                       option(name="rarity" type="option")=val
           button#refresh(type="submit") Refresh
```

Current post data:

```
{
 artist: 'aaa',
 name: 'sasas',
 mina: '11',
 maxa: '23',
 minh: '44',
 maxh: '5'
}
```

Comment: add the name attr to your `select` and then use it like your other inputs

Comment: @UmerLachi I tried adding it to the select as select(name='class') for both but it does not POST the one selected

Comment: Please add post data to your question

Comment: @UmerLachi Currently it doesn't post any of the options, it posts everything else fine.

Comment: Can you see options in the HTML? please share the response you get when posting.

Comment: @UmerLachi Options are displayed in HTML properly, I posted the post data above

Comment: Did you add the name attribute to your selects?

Comment: Try: `select#rarity(name="rarity")`

Comment: @UmerLachi I got it to work, for some reason the type=option was breaking things but the select#rarity(name="rarity") works, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome ;)

Answer (score 0):

Code was fixed like this for the option forms:

```
       p Class: 
            select#class(name="class")
                each val in options
                    option=val
                    
        p Rarity:
            select#rarity(name="rarity")
                each val in rarity2
                    option=val
```